# Handling grammatical gender with Angular-Gettext

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gettext, angular-gettext

I'm looking for a simple-proper-elegant way to handle grammatical gender with Angular-Gettext.
Is it possible to do something with the translate-plural directive or by using ng-pluralize ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently. Gettext doesn't natively support that.

Answer received by rubenv

[Angular GetText grammatical gender issue](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext/issues/39)

Comment: Though, it should be noted, it could be added: it's just a matter of extracting and selecting the right strings (it'd basically be a layer on top of gettext). The challenge is to make the API of this usable.